# Create a function within interface to format date so it can be displayed in render

Tags: javascript, typescript, sharepoint-online, spfx

I'm getting errors when attempting to format a date into a readable format using `.toLocaleDateString()`:

```
private _onRenderCell = (item: IEIAItem) => {
  
  let create1 = item.Created;
  let create2 = create1.toLocaleDateString(); //this causes the error
      return (
        <div>
          <tr>
            <td style={{ width: '80px' }}>{item.EIARef}</td>
            <td style={{ width: '250px' }}>{item.PPName}</td>
            <td style={{ width: '80px' }}>{create2}</td>//this causes the error
            <td style={{ width: '100px' }}>{item.PolicyOwnerTitle}</td>
            <td style={{ width: '200px' }}>{item.Department}</td>
            <td style={{ width: '100px' }}>{item.FormStatus}</td>
            <td style={{ width: '15px' }}>
            <div className={styles.editIcon}><Icon iconName="Edit" id={item.Id.toString()} onClick={this._editItem} />
            </div>
           </td>
          </tr>
     
        </div>
      );
    }
```

The above code displays a list of items from an SPO list. It uses an interface to bring through the data into the list.

The data interface/model works correctly, but if I replace `item.Created` with anything but `item.Created` it throws an error `(toLocaleDateString is not a function...)`. I've looked for solutions up and down but nothing I've found really covers this. I'm thinking it needs to either use `.map` in the `_onRenderCell` method, or use the `.toLocaleDateString()` within the interface itself. Need help with this one please.

Comment: let create1 = new Date(item.Created)  and you have to ensure that item.Created is in correct form.

Comment: _"I'm getting errors"_.  _"it throws an error"_.  Always best to quote the specific error you're getting.

Comment: Added the error, thanks.

Comment: @Robert - was over-thinking that one, *slightly embarrased* Thanks.

Comment: It's probably just that your date is still a string.  Probably came from JSON where Date is not natively supported and dates are formatted as strings.

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
private _onRenderCell = (item: IEIAItem) => {
         const Role = this.state.CurrentUserRole;
             let create1 = new Date(item.Created);
             let create2 = create1.toLocaleDateString();
         return (
           <div>
             <tr>
               <td style={{ width: '80px' }}>{item.EIARef}</td>
               <td style={{ width: '250px' }}>{item.PPName}</td>
               <td style={{ width: '80px' }}>{create2}</td>
               <td style={{ width: '100px' }}>{item.PolicyOwnerTitle}</td>
               <td style={{ width: '200px' }}>{item.Department}</td>
               <td style={{ width: '100px' }}>{item.FormStatus}</td>
               <td style={{ width: '15px' }}>
                 <div className={styles.editIcon}><Icon iconName="Edit" id={item.Id.toString()} onClick={this._editItem} />
                 </div>
               </td>
             </tr>
     
           </div>
         );
       }
```